# how to call Calendar.getInstance in NDK using C++?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have looked but can not find the answer to this, I am trying to instantiate a Calendar object in C++ using the NDK. I have tried using both AllocObject and NewObject, both yield the same result.

Here is my Java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final static String TAG = "TestJNIConstructor";
private native Calendar getCalendarObject();

static
{
    System.loadLibrary("myjni");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Calendar cal = getCalendarObject();
    Log.d(TAG, "cal = " + cal.toString());
}
```

and here is my C++ code

```
#include "TestJNIConstructor.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_example_testjniconstructor_MainActivity_getCalendarObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
{
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/util/Calendar");

    jmethodID midInit = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getInstance", "()Ljava/util/Calendar");
    if(NULL==midInit)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    //jobject newObj = env->NewObject(cls, midInit);
    jobject newObj = env->AllocObject(cls);
    return newObj;


}
```

and the .h

```
#include <jni.h>

    extern "C" {
        JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_example_testjniconstructor_MainActivity_getCalendarObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj);
    }
```

the error I get is:

04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='getInstance' signature='()Ljava/util/Calendar' in class Ljava/util/Calendar;
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at com.example.testjniconstructor.MainActivity.getCalendarObject(Native Method)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at com.example.testjniconstructor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
04-14 16:16:09.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10678):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar's getInstance() is a static method, you need to change `env->GetMethodID` to `env->GetStaticMethodID`

Comment: I am getting the error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='getInstance' signature='()I' in class Ljava/util/Calendar;
 I added -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    native <methods>; to proguard-project.txt but that did not help, so I am assuming the problem is with the signature, I have tried both ()I and ()Ljava/util/Calendar with no luck, any ideas?

Comment: Did you forget the semicolon? "()Ljava/util/Calendar;"

Comment: yes I did, thank you for all your help -- dyslexics of the world, UNTIE

Comment: Np :p a check would be nice.

Comment: The final piece of the puzzle was to replace: newObj = env->NewObject(cls, midInit); with  newObj = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls, midInit); -- and it really, really works!